# How to get bokeh to dynamically adjust y_range when panning

Tags: python, r, bokeh

I have a long time series with a varying Y range across time.  At the same time have limited the X range / viewport to a smaller time period so that can see detail.  As the data is panned horizontally, bokeh does not adjust the Y range based on visible data in the viewport.

Here is an example in rbokeh (can provide the equivalent in python if useful):

```
require(rbokeh)

x <- seq(as.Date('2010-1-1'), as.Date('2017-1-1'), by='days')
len <- NROW(x)
y <- (1:len) * 5e-2 + rnorm(len, sd=10)

range <- c(x[1], x[200])

figure(width=800,height=300, xlim=range) %>%
    ly_lines (x, y) %>%
    tool_pan(dimensions='width')
```

The visual that this produces shows a y range of -25 to 150, expressing the extent of the whole series, but reducing the detail visible in the viewport due to the smaller range of the visible data:
[image: what I get now]

I would like to see the initial range to show -25 to 30, in line with the visible points (as shown below) and to subsequently change the Y range when the data is panned horizontally.
[image: what I would like to see]

**Question**

Is there a way to turn on auto-scaling / range adjusting behavior in bokeh so that is done on the client-side.  Is there a widget option or js injection that would make this work?

Both python and R implementations of Bokeh make use of the core coffee / JS library, so suspect this question is relevant to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some pointers from the bokeh community, determined a solution.  I would hope that this could be added as an option in the future so as to avoid writing (somewhat brittle) JS code.

Here is the solution:

```
yrange.callback <- function (var, margin=0.15)
{    
    code <- sprintf ("
        var plot = cb_obj.plots[0];

        var data = %s_data.get('data');
        var x = data['x'];
        var y = data['y'];

        var Xstart = plot.x_range.start;
        var Xend = plot.x_range.end;

        function sGE (e) { return e >= Xstart; } 
        function eGE (e) { return e >= Xend; } 
        function fixstart (i) { return i >= 0 ? i : x.length - 20; } 
        function fixend (i) { return i > 0 ? i : x.length - 1; } 

        var Istart = fixstart(x.findIndex(sGE))
        var Iend = fixend(x.findIndex(eGE))

        var yview = y.slice(Istart, Iend+1);
        var ymin = Math.min(...yview);
        var ymax = Math.max(...yview);
        var dy = ymax - ymin;

        var margin = %f * dy;
        cb_obj.start = ymin - margin;
        cb_obj.end = ymax + margin;", var, margin)

    custom_callback(code, lnames=var)
}

x <- seq(as.Date('2010-1-1'), as.Date('2017-1-1'), by='days')
len <- NROW(x)
y <- (1:len) * 5e-2 + rnorm(len, sd=10)

## render
range <- c(x[1], x[200])

figure(width=800,height=300, xlim=range) %>%
    ly_lines (x, y, lname = "points", lgroup='g1') %>%
    y_range(callback = yrange.callback('points'))
```

I had to attach this to the `r_range` callback as opposed to the `x_range` callback as the `cb_obj` on a callback for x_range would be the x_range object, hence putting the event callback on `y_range` provided the y range object for modification.   I could not determine a way to modify the y_range on the plot object in such as way as to update.